# $_GET for + in url get request?

Tags: php, yii, get

My project Url is like this in yii:

```
 http://localhost/php_pro_106/activate/Test?JJ=HEY+OOO
```

In my action :

```
public function actionTest()
   {
   print_r($_GET);
 }
```

I am getting:

```
 Array ( [JJ] => HEY OOO )
```

But I should get:

```
 Array ( [JJ] => HEY+OOO )
```

What should I do for this,I need same Url ?

Comment: You can not have the exact same URL and get the + sign. You can however encode your URL. `urlencode()`

Comment: That's because the `+` was a way of encoding a space for urls, though people should be using `%20` (in the query component).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `+` in a URL means a space. So you get the result you should have.

If you want to encode a `+` character in a URL, then you should represent it as `%2B`.

```
http://localhost/php_pro_106/activate/Test?JJ=HEY%2BOOO
```

If you are generating the URL programatically with PHP, you can use the `urlencode` function.

```
$keyname = "JJ";
$data = "HEY+OOO";
$url = "http://localhost/php_pro_106/activate/Test?" . urlencode($keyname) . "=" . urlencode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your URL (e.g. with `urlencode` in php). `+` needs to become `%2B`.

```
http://localhost/php_pro_106/activate/Test?JJ=HEY%2BOOO
```

Answer (score 0):

"+" is one of reserved characters, according to RFC 2396.

If you want "+" in your example, you should use url encoding.

```
http://localhost/php_pro_106/activate/Test?JJ=HEY%2BOOO
```

If you produce URL from code, use urlencode() function to generate your URLS.